# Not able to switch screen in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have below files i  am trying to switch to new windows once the button on homescreen is pressed but it throws error 'No Screen with name "VerifyScreen"'

I debugged a bit and copy pasted the Screen: part from verifyscreen.kv to our homescreen.kv file and it started working.

But why its not able to get the screen even i get the two kv files in starting only??

homescreen.kv

```
<HomeScreen>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    screen_manager: screen_manager
    ScreenManager:
        size_hint: 1, 1
        id: screen_manager
        Screen:
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                name: 'Home_Screen'
                id: 'home'
                Label: 
                    markup: True
                    text: 'Home-Panel'
                Button:
                    text: 'submitt'
                    size_hint: 1,1
                    id: submitt
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
                    on_press:
                        root.verify()
```

verifyscreen.kv

```
<VerifyScreen>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    verify_screen_manager: verify_screen_manager
    ScreenManager:
        size_hint: 1, 1
        id: verify_screen_manager
        Screen:
            name: 'VerifyScreen'
            id: verify_screen
```

main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from functools import partial
import os
import random
import kivy
kivy.require('1.8.0')
#all required modules are imported 
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager


slides = [ "HomeScreen","VerifyScreen" ]

for slide in slides:
    kv_file = "{}.kv".format(slide.lower())
    Builder.load_file(os.path.join("slides", kv_file))


class HomeScreen(Screen):
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty(None)
    verify_screen_manager = ObjectProperty(None)
    verify_screen = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(HomeScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = 'vertical'

    def verify(self):
        print "manish"
        #self.screen_manager.current = 'VerifyScreen'
        self.screen_manager.switch_to(self.verify_screen)

class HomeScreenApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return HomeScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    HomeScreenApp().run()
```

Comment: that's not how it work, screen_manager.current = 'VerifyScreen' requires that screen_manager have a Screen instance, e.i: (add it with add_widget() method) with the name 'VerifyScreen', otherwise you can switch dynamicaly using switch_to(), => http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html?highlight=screenmanager#advanced-usage

Comment: @FIns i have added self.screen_manager.switch_to(self.verify_screen) but still it gives    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/uix/screenmanager.py", line 1010, in switch_to
     assert(screen is not None)
 Does this mean that screen widget needs to be empty i.e. without any button etc. ?

Comment: ```<HomeScreen>``` has no ```verify_screen```, so ```self.verify_screen``` will be ```None``` in your call to ```.switch_to```.  There appear to be several issues with your code, but I can't tell what you are trying to do...

Comment: @bj0 my understanding was that  instead of looking into <HomeScreen>it will look into <VerifyScreen> which has verify_screen as id . What did i missed or is my understanding wrong ?

Comment: you are calling ```.switch_to``` on the ```ScreenManager``` in ```<HomeScreen>```, which is tagged ```verify_screen```.  That ```ScreenManater``` has only one Screen, which is unlabelled in your code sample.  As far as I can see there is no ```VerifyScreen``` instantiated in your code at all.